# MCP23S17 GPIO daisy chain wiring

Tags: gpio

I am searching for some reading materials that outlines the method by which you can daisy chain 16x MCP23S17 (SPI) to achieve 512 GPIO on a Rpi. I would like to experiment with the maximum number of GPIO with a range of sensors and LED's, and so far my searches have turned up only chatter about how it could be done, and nothing about if it has.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: https://www.instructables.com/Raspberry-Pi-Port-Expander/

Comment: Thanks. I have seen this and a lot of the pins are incorrect. Referring to datasheet prevails

Comment: Well, I have experimented with both MCP23017 and MCP23S17. For 017 I have successfully put and detect 8 017s on a single bus, but not reliable or stable, and two or three seems a reasonable limit. For s17, the trouble is you need 8 rpi gpio pins to CS 8 s17s, or use HC137.138 to do muxing.

Comment: Yes, I use through hole versions of 008, 017, s08, s17 to start learning. Now I am using assembled modules from AliX. Using modules save a lot to deve time.